# Tortoise SVN Merge: Branch->Trunk with Revision History from both Tree

Tags: tortoisesvn

we cut branch from Trunk. Changes are done on both trees and committed. Now we want to merge branch to trunk with all the revision history from both. Is it possible?

Is manual merge is different from tortoise SVN merge say i have to do 3-4 files?
"Means i manually check the changes then do it on trunk and commit the trunk."

I earlier put a question regarding it but still confused.
Experts comment only.

Thx

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to merge from your branch to trunk by simply right clicking on the target branch and selecting merge.  Typically, a reintegrate merge will merge all changes from a branch back into the target branch.  I have had failures with that in the past based on the version of svn, how merges have been done in the past, etc.  At that point, I simply would do a 'Merge revision range' without specifying a revision.  It then picked up the appropriate ranges to merge and successfully pulled those over to trunk.

Once the merge is done, you must commit the merges.  Simply put, the merge operation completes on your local working copy.  You will then have to commit the changes to your working copy in order for others to pick it up.  I recommend doing merges on clean copies of branches/targets (meaning you have no outstanding changes on either branch).  Also, make sure you commit any property changes as well.

Lastly, if you just want to merge a specific change, you can specify the revision in which the change was made instead of doing a full merge/reintegration.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you are asking.  Can you give very specific details?

Comment: I think that the questioner was interested in the history.

Since subversion 1.6, the history can display revisions from merged in branches if you choose to see it.

In tortoiseSVN it is a checkbox 'include merged revisions' - similar in subclipse, comand line etc

Comment: I think Neil Stevens' comment should be added to the answer, this is in my opinion what was asked